# Forward Engineering Database in MySQL Workbench - Error 1304: FUNCTION GET_NEXT_SEQ already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am new to Mysql workbench and I am trying to forward engineer a EER model to a test database, however when I do so I get this error and I am not sure what it means.

I'm tempted to remove the function definition as it's already defined elsewhere which I imagine would solve this error, however because I don't know if the original definition is the same as the new one I'm reluctant to just trust this method.

> Executing SQL script in server
>       ERROR: Error 1304: FUNCTION GET_NEXT_SEQ already exists

SQL Code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`masteruser`@`%` FUNCTION `GET_NEXT_SEQ`(`SEQNAME` VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
  DECLARE CURVALUE INT; 
  UPDATE sequence_log SET CURRENT_VALUE = (CURRENT_VALUE + 1) WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = SEQNAME;
  SELECT CURRENT_VALUE INTO CURVALUE FROM sequence_log WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = SEQNAME;
  RETURN LPAD(CURVALUE,9,0);
END
```

I got the EER from reverse engineering the same database.

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GET_NEXT_SEQ_VAL`(`SEQNAME` VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8
        BEGIN
        DECLARE CURVALUE INT; 
        UPDATE sequence_log SET CURRENT_VALUE = (CURRENT_VALUE + 1) WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = SEQNAME;
        SELECT CURRENT_VALUE INTO CURVALUE FROM sequence_log WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = SEQNAME;
        RETURN LPAD(CURVALUE,9,0);
        END
```

You can simply create new function with new name.